# Is this "legal" microservices design?

Tags: design-patterns, service, architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices

**Setup:**

- Within the whole system, there is a concept of a list of items for each customer and this needs to a concept understood by multiple services A, B, C.
- Those same multiple services perform distinct type of work that operates on that list of items.
- It's ok if B or C is operating on a version of the list of items that is not up-to-date, so long as they eventually get the latest version.

**My design:**

- One service A is the source of truth for the current state of the list of items. The list is manipulated in this service.
- When the list changes, A publishes the list and B and C, subscribers to this event, store copies of it in their own storage.
- When B and C do their work, they use their local copy of the list.
- B and C also have additional state specific to their domain.

**My rationale:**

Since B and C don't ask A for the list when they do their work, they are not dependent on A. If for some reason A goes down, the impact to the system is only that B and C don't have up-to-date information, which is acceptable, and which will be mitigated when A is fixed.

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Sounds like the Observer Pattern; but you should ask a more specific question to get a more specific answer. "_Is there anything wrong,_" is subjective and too broad a question for SO.

Comment: There's nothing wrong wit it. You can check this video that explains comcepts similar to what you are doint https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STKCRSUsyP0. It's true that the question is too broad.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach. It is the standard way of data integration between microservices.

Answer (score 0):

B and C have what's known as a Cache.  It's acceptable when it's out-of-date, just make a way to validate with A what the version that is current is (last-modified datetime is often used) and you will be fine.